# need help in installing bitcoincore?

Tags: node.js, npm

i keep getting this error

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\eze samuel\package.json'
npm WARN eze samuel No description
npm WARN eze samuel No repository field.
npm WARN eze samuel No README data
npm WARN eze samuel No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bitcore"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bitcore-node@3.1.3 preinstall: `./scripts/download`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bitcore-node@3.1.3 preinstall script './scripts/download'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bitcore-node package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./scripts/download
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bitcore-node
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bitcore-node
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\eze samuel\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`bitcore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcore) library explicitly tells you to install globally:

> Spin up a full node and join the network:
>
> ```
> npm install -g bitcore
> bitcored
> ```

Note the `-g`  flag in the command. Currently, you're running `npm install bitcore`, which fails because you're trying to install locally without a `package.json` file. If you're not installing with `-g`, you **must** run `npm init` first before installing anything. In this case, you **are** installing with `-g`, so just follow the docs step by step, copying **exactly** what they tell you.